# Let $T: M_{22} \to M_{22}$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(A) = AB-BA$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: M_{22} \to M_{22}$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(A) = AB-BA$ where $B =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then prove or disprove that Ker(T) and R(T) are isomorphic

If we apply a linear transformation on the kernel of the transformation, the transformed product is a zero vector always, so it’s clearly not one one and hence it’s not isomorphic. But I am having serious doubts over the validity of this proof, so can anyone verify if it is correct or not?

Comment: The question doesn't ask if $T$ is an isomorphism between the kernel and the range, this is clearly not the case. The question is if the two vector spaces $Ker(T)$ and $R(T)$ are isomorphic in general. (i.e whether there is some isomorphism between them)

Comment: @Mark is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Note that two finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension, so we want to prove that they have the same dimension. We also know that $4=dim(M_{22})=dim(Ker(T))+dim(R(T))$. Let's calculate the dimension of $Ker(T)$.
$$A\in Ker(T) \iff T(A)=AB-BA=0 \iff AB=BA$$
Let's $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\;$, so $AB=BA \iff$ $c=0$ and $a=d$. So we have that a basis for $Ker(T)$ is generated by $\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\;,\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\}$, hence $dim(Ker(T))=2=dim(R(T))$

Comment: I thought dimensions behind equal was a necessary but insufficient condition